# Reading UUID from database with Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a database table with a PK field called id. id is varchar(16).
I have a function that generates a UUIDlike string (16 chars from 0-F). When I store a new record, I can see that the database has received the string, but when I call the model for display on a page, the string only shows up to the first ALPHA char (unless it starts with an ALPHA char, in which case I get 0).

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: have you added `protected $increments = false;` to the model?

Comment: `public $incrementing` that was exactly it. I guess Eloquent casts PKs to int. Thanks jfadich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Laravel will expect the id to be an incrementing integer. Since that is not the case here you have to tell Laravel that by adding this to your model.

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I had been reading about Eloquent but apparently glossed over that part.